# documentReference.data(as: ) not available anymore in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I'm trying to access the documentReference.data(as: ) but it seems like it wouldn't show on my end. I was wondering if this method is deprecated? if so is there any alternative method I can use  to map a document reference to a Swift type.

Here's a screenshot of my code:

[documentReference.data(as: ) not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWU1I.png)

What I'm try to do is something like this.

```
func fetchOccupants() async throws -> [Occupant] {
    let snapshot = try await occupantsRef.getDocuments()
    
    
    return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
        try? document.data(as: Occupants.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the Firebase header show? Is this method included?

Comment: The [Firestore DocumentSnapshot documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot.html) doesn't have this method listed. Are you sure it ever existed? Could it be so that in other projects in the past you had an extension method with this signature?

Comment: Hi @VadimBelyaev, yes, it is also included in their documentation here's the link for context https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of testing and reading some documentation I finally solved it. It seems like using Cocoapods to add FirebaseFirestoreSwift is not working, so I tried using Swift Package Manager instead since it's more updated Package Manager for Swift.

Following this method works for me [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
Apparently, at some point this method was moved to a separate module `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` (or maybe it was always there, I might be wrong).

Import this module and the method `data(as:with:decoder:)` becomes available:

```swift
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

It's also mentioned on the documentation page about Codable: [Map Cloud Firestore data with Swift Codable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping).

Comment: Hi I've try adding the  FirebaseFirestoreSwift as you said but I got an error "No such module FirebaseFirestoreSwift" I even try adding it to my pod file using this pod "FirebaseFirestoreSwift"

Comment: Also, is FirebaseFirestore different from FirebaseFirestoreSwift?

Comment: Yes, it's different and it depends on FirebaseFirestore. When you added FirebaseFirestoreSwift to the Podfile, did you get any errors when running `pod install` after that?